# The "Ask Question" link opens up previous question in "Edit" mode.

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

Clicking on "Ask Question" takes me to [expected URL](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask):, ***but*** the displayed page is primed with the **tags**, **title**, and **contents** of my [previous question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8998/why-does-kdes-konsole-not-have-top-level-menu-accelerator-keys-is-it-a-bug-is):

What is going on here?  I have tried two different browsers, with the same result...  Firefox and Konqueror.

Does it have anything to do with the weekend's data migration (perhaps)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Drafts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1177/54262) are a relatively new feature, and this could be a bug: saved draft is brought up again, even though that question has been posted.

Just clear the fields and enter your different question.  It may be affected by the migration, we should wait until that's done before submitting a bug.

Comment: Okay... Thanks  (I did have something go haywire yesterday and I had to reboot (endless terminals poping up) I must have had unposted contend sitting there at the time)